# Excluding terms (category names) by ID for current post

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this function to display the terms attached to a post but i can't manage to find a way to exclude specific ID's of some category terms i don't want to display in the list.
Could someone give me a clue were to start? I looked up all the functions used in this function but can't seem to find arguments to exclude id's.

Thanks in advance!

```
   // get taxonomies terms links
   function custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
   global $post, $post_id;
   // get post by post id
   $post = &get_post($post->ID);
   // get post type by post
   $post_type = $post->post_type;
   // get post type taxonomies
   $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
   $out = "<ul>";
   foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {        
       // get the terms related to post
       $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
       if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
           foreach ( $terms as $term )
               $out .= '<li><a href="' .get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) .'">'.$term->name.'</a></li> ';
        }
    }
    $out .= "</ul>";
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another conditional `if` statement within your second `foreach()` to check whether or not the `$term` should be ignored. For example:

```
// An array of IDs to ignore/exclude
$excluded_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4);

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // Only proceed if the term_id is NOT in the $excluded_ids array
    if ( !in_array( $term->term_id, $excluded_ids ) ) {
        $out .= '<li><a href="' .get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) .'">'.$term->name.'</a></li> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response.
But when i enter the different id's i dont want to see it ends up only showing the names of the category names i want to exclude

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. It sounds like you're missing the `!` before `in_array(`

Comment: Ok sorry i did something wrong :) . it works perfect! Thanks alot !!